# Flask-SQLAlchemy dilemma: single/separate classes for one business logic object

Tags: python, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

Perhaps this is one of the culture-dependent questions, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

So, in the [docs of Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/), we are encouraged to establish our models by declaring db.Model-derived classes:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'USR_User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

however, my database fields, by ancient convention, are kind of ugly: USR_User.usrID, USR_User.usrName, etc.

I'd like my Python User objects to be cleaner and have properties without the "usr" prefix, and also have some other nice methods that are not necessarily connected with the database connection.

So, the question arises, whether I should declare the alternative field names in that single class, like this

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'USR_User'
    id = Column('usrID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('usrName', String(50))

    ... and all the methods
```

Or, I should keep the datatable-connected model separate from the business logic model and join them with a mapper (I am not sure what would be the right way how to do it under Flask-SQLAlchemy though).

I am not sure if such separation brings any benefits, but I kind of feel intuitive urge to keep the two classes separate.

Comment: It seems like you've found all of the possible solutions for this particular problem, and are soliciting opinions for which one is "best".  That's not quite on topic for this site.

Comment: Maybe, but in that case I am not aware of it. I am still learning the philosophy of SQLAlchemy. This questions of single ORM-mapped class vs separate clases for database mapping and business logic is still very open for me.

Comment: You can 1: name attributes in your mapped classes according to the names in the database, 2:rename them, or 3:introduce a layer of abstraction between your business logic and persistence.  Which one is right for your particular situation only you can answer.